# Why does this MySql query lead to inconsistent results?

Tags: mysql

I have a table called `summary` that holds summaries of staff activity.  Each week I run a process that creates a new summary record for any employees who have had sales activity that week.

Whenever a record is created I want to link it back to the last summary for the given employee, where such a record exists.  Therefore, I start the process by collecting the most recent summary for each employee, using the following query:

```
select * from `summary` where id in (select max(id) from summary group by (staff_id))
```

As far as I can tell, the query does not always return the true 'max' for each employee, and as a result I end up with multiple records pointing to the same earlier record (rather than their immediate predecessor).  For example, if an employee has 5 summary records with the id's of 10, 20, 30, 40, 50 I might end up with:

- 10 points to NULL (correct)
- 20 points to 10 (correct)
- 30 points to 10 (incorrect)
- 40 points to 10 (incorrect)
- 50 points to 40 (correct)

The records for some employees are fine, and I can't find any pattern to when the problem occurs.  (It's difficult to diagnose because it is a large database, and once the process has been run the updates are committed to the DB, so it's difficult to go back to the earlier state).

The ID field in the summary database is an auto-incrementing primary key.

Comment: Sample data would be nice and desired result.

Comment: Impossible to say without knowing the table and data...

Answer (score 0):

Try using alias as you refer twice to the same table summary, so the id might be confusing

```
select * from `summary` as s1  where s1.id in (select max(s2.id) from summary as s2 group by s2.staff_id)
```

I tried to run similar query and it works properly on my environment (even without alias)